# Laravel, Datatables and Model Hydrate

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.6

Summary of problem or feature request

I need to use hydrate to fill a model that is not linked to a database. But in doing so I can't use the datatable() call for laravel.

```
    $query = "EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_controlclient]  '$XML' ";
    DB::connection('sqlsrvreplicate')->reconnect();
    $data = DB::connection('sqlsrvreplicate')->select($query);

    $ReportData = $Model->hydrate($data);
    return datatables()->collection($ReportData)->toJson();
```

What I need to get

```
"data": [
[
  "Tiger Nixon",
  "System Architect"
],
[
  "Garrett Winters",
  "Accountant"
],
```

What I actually get

```
"data": [{
  "Name":"Tiger Nixon",
  "Job":"System Architect"
},
{
  "Name":"Garrett Winters",
  "Job":"Accountant"
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the way you are returning the value. Check the last method of this line:

```php
return datatables()->collection($ReportData)->toJson();
```

With `toJson()` you are returning the data as an `json` object, that is why you get:

```php
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "Job": "System Architect"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Garrett Winters",
      "Job": "Accountant"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead, you could do this:

```php
return datatables()->collection($ReportData)->toArray();
```

Now, if you are using this for an API, you could parse the `json` as an `array` in the client side. If your client is written in php, just do:

```php
$my_fancy_array = json_decode($received_data, true);
```